# Haskell MTL: How to exit the monad and get the value within it?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers, state-monad

I know how to use functions from each monad inside a `do` block. But once i'm finished how do I run the computation and get the result?

```
run :: (MonadError Error m, MonadState State m) => m Int -> Int
run = ???
```

Comment: Keep in mind that for most monads, obtaining the exact type `m Int -> Int` is impossible. When you run `m Int` you will get, at best, some type with `Int` inside, instead. This return type depends on the actual `m`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of `mtl` is that you don't specify your concrete monad transformer stack - you just specify that it has to handle errors and hold state.

However, once you actually want to run this action, you *do* need to tie yourself down to a particular monad transformer stack. That stack will inform how you can "run" your monadic action. In your case, it looks like you probably want to go with `ExcepT Error (State State)`:

```
action :: (MonadError Error m, MonadState State m) => m Int
action = undefined

runAction :: State ->           -- initial state
             Either Error Int   -- account for possibility of error
runAction initialState = evalState (runExceptT action) initialState
```

Note that this *isn't* the only choice of a concrete stack you could have made. In fact, you could even swap the order of the `State` and `Except` and choose `StateT State (Either Error)` as your monad!

```
runAction :: State ->           -- initial state
             Either Error Int   -- account for possibility of error
runAction initialState = evalState action initialState
```

The fact that `mtl` says nothing about the *order* of monads in your stack is one of its shortcomings (and one of the reasons why some people prefer to just stick with `transformers`).

Comment: How does the order of monads affect the execution? what happens if you switch `ExcepT Error (State State)` for `StateT State (Either Error)`

Comment: @user47376 Try expanding the newtypes. You'll see that `ExceptT e (State s) a ~ State s (Either e a) ~ s -> (Either e a, s)` whereas `StateT s (Except e) a ~ s -> Except e (a, s) ~ s -> Either e (a, s)`. The former gives error handlers access to the value of the state at the point of the error, although [the standard implementation of `catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.html#liftCatch) doesn't do this.